# Generate 4 dynamic buttons and floating labels per row

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I have a table `services`. Using **SQL** I am retrieving all data into this loop:

```
           using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString"))
            {
                try
                {

                    using (var cmd = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString"))
                    {

                        var select3 = "SELECT name,number FROM services";

                        // Open connection
                        cmd.Open();
                        // Create command
                        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(select3, cmd);
                        // Create data reader
                        SqlDataReader rdr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                        // Loop through result set


                        while (rdr3.Read())
                        {

                          Button b = new Button();
                            b.Location = new Point(150 * (i % 4) + 12, 30 * i + 10);
                            b.Height = 179;
                            b.Width = 119;
                            b.Text = (rdr3["number"].ToString().Trim());
                            b.Name = string.Format("b_{0}", i + 1);
                            //b.Click += b_Click;
                            //b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                            Controls.Add(b);

                            Label lbl = new Label();
                            lbl.Location = new Point(150 * (i % 4) + 12, 30 * i + 10);
                            lbl.Text = (rdr3["name"].ToString().Trim());
                            lbl.Tag = i;
                            Controls.Add(lbl);
//end dynamic generation
                        }
                        // Close data reader
                        rdr3.Close();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error during insert! " + ex);
                }
            }
```

*The only problem with this code is that all buttons and labels are shoved in the first row like this:

[image: c sharp buttons and labels generation problem]

So I would like this loop to display **ONLY** 4 buttons and 4 labels **per each line** and there is **no limit for rows count**. Results should be something like this:

[image: Generate 4 buttons and 4 labels per each line]

**Hint:** *Please do not bother with **FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel**, because They are not appropriate as they tend not to allow a Label to float in (x,x) location above a button.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the Location property of the button and label

```
b.Location = new Point(12, 30 * i + 10);
```

However, you are only varying the location in one direction with regard to `i`. You probably need to vary both directions. Something like

```
b.Location = new Point( 100 * (i/4) + 12, 30 * (i%4) + 10);
```

By increasing the first value by multiples of `i/4`, you move the buttons down every 4, and by changing the second value to use multiples of `i%4`, the value resets on each new row.

You will probably need to play with the value multiplied by `i/4` to get something that looks reasonable for your needs.

Comment: Thank you!! I just upvoted you for this intuitive explanation!!  I got to play around with your suggestion and now this seems closer enough to resolve the problem `Location = new Point(200 * (i % 4) + 12, 30 * (i / 4) + 10);`

This is how it looks like: https://image.prntscr.com/image/LxQ98VP2SYyUAyKfSe5Hug.png

Could you help more variables ? THanks

Comment: It's a good reply but it still doesn't answer the question. I will wait if someone comes with something.

Comment: Thank you again! I have managed a good workaround and it is really awesome!! <3